# List of unique words from data.frame

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R, so please be patient with me.

I have a vector of characters with a column that describes illnesses and diagnosis keywords in an inconsistent format. Samples are:

```
flu
fever/feverish
fever cold
```

I'm looking for the best way to extract all unique words from this. The best process I could figure out this far is giving me a vector of vectors:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "flu"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "fever" "feverish"
...
```

I achieve this by using:

```
split_words <- function(x){ strsplit(x, "[^[:alpha:]]+") }
lapply(diagnoses, split_words)
```

What is the best approach to convert this into a single vector or single column data frame so that I can run `unique` on this vector and remove duplicates.

What are the best packages on R to do word stemming to remove similar spellings, plurals etc.

Comment: All guaranteed lowercase? Split and discard on any whitespace or punctuation? Are you sure that '/' or '-' are always irrelevant? What about e.g. *Guillain-Barre syndrome*?

Comment: I have checked all terms with with "-" and "/" and the actual regexp is a bit more complex. But I wanted to simplify the question. I am running tolower and unique on the full list of illnesses before getting to this stage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `unlist` after `strsplit` to get the vector with all elements,  and `unique` for the unique elements.

```
x <- c("flu", "fever/feverish", "fever cold")
( ul <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s+|[[:punct:]]")) )
# [1] "flu"      "fever"    "feverish" "fever"    "cold"  
unique(ul)
# [1] "flu"      "fever"    "feverish" "cold"
```

Comment: Split on selective punctuation. Split on `[.,;:]` don't split on `[-/]`

Answer (score 2):

```
# > df
#         illness
#1            flu
#2 fever/feverish
#3     fever cold   


udf <- unlist(strsplit(df$illness, "[^[:alnum:]]"))
# [1] "flu"      "fever"    "feverish" "fever"    "cold"

table(udf)
#udf
#    cold    fever feverish      flu 
#       1        2        1        1
```